# How to publish a paid app to play sore

Tags: android, publish

I know how to publish a free and paid app.I found that paid app need some Lib as licence verification library(LVL) for Paid App and have to integrate this LVL to the App.Please say the process what are thing to be added to a app  to make it published as paid app.Thanks in Advances

Comment: Sandeep, it's unclear whether you are asking about the process of submitting a paid app to the Play Store, or whether you are asking about how and why to implement license checking inside your app. It is **not necessary to implement license checking inside your app in order to have it published as a paid-for app on the Play Store**. More info on app licensing is available here (including implementation): http://developer.android.com/google/play/licensing/index.html

Comment: sorry for unclear..is it same as free app publish.there is no need to add LVL to app

Comment: It's the same process as publishing a free app, except instead of £0.00, you set a price.

Comment: Their is no need to add any lvl to app

Comment: sorry for asking this question.just for clarity i am asking it..have u published any paid app?